# How to take all the values that exist from a complicated dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Assume we have multiple complicated dictionaries with different formats, is there a way to extract all the values in an automated way?

For example:

```
a = {1:2,3:4,4:{1:5}}
a.values()
[2,4,{1:5}]
```

But what I want is the following:

```
[2,4,5]
```

And how can I manage the case of the following dictionary:

```
b = {1:2,3:4,5:[{6:7,8:9},{10:11}]}
```

to output:

```
[2,4,7,9,11]
```

Comment: Dictionaries have no inherent ordering, so any solution would have to either 1) limit its input to dictionaries containing sortable keys, or 2) not care about multiple equally-valid outputs for a given input.  In your example, the keys are all sortable... is that something you can safely assume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isinstance` function to check for the type of an item.

```
>>> def extract(d):
    for i,j in d.items():
        if isinstance(j, dict):
            for x in j.values():
                yield x
        else:
            yield j


>>> list(extract({1:2,3:4,4:{1:5}}))
[2, 4, 5]
```

**Update:**

```
>>> def extract(d):
    for i,j in d.items():
        if isinstance(j, dict):
            for x in extract(j):
                yield x
        else:
            yield j


>>> list(extract({1:2,3:4,4:{1:{5:6}}}))
[2, 4, 6]
```

Final Update:

```
>>> def extract(d):
    for i,j in d.items():
        if isinstance(j, dict):
            for x in extract(j):
                yield x
        elif isinstance(j, list):
            for k in j:
                if isinstance(k, dict):
                    for l in extract(k):
                        yield l
        else:
            yield j


>>> list(extract({1:2,3:4,5:[{6:7,8:9},{10:11}]}))
[2, 4, 9, 7, 11]
```

Comment: `d.items` will produce key-value pairs in a mostly unpredictable order, so you can't guarantee this will produce the same (or even sensible) output for the same input.  It appears to work here, because non-negative integer keys just happen to hash into a typical python `dict` in the order they arrived... at least in some versions of Python.  The same input `dict` with _negative_ integer keys (`{-1:2, -3:4, -5:[{-6:7, -8:9}, {-10:11}]}`) produces the kind of disorder you could expect of most other key types: `[9, 7, 11, 4, 2]`.

Comment: If you loop over `sorted(d)` instead of `d.items()`, the keys will arrive in a predictable order... maybe not the order the OP wants, but at least predictable.